# How to stop Devforce 7.2.3 deleting partial classes

Tags: devforce

Ever since I upgraded to Devforce 7.2.3 and use Entity Framework 6.1 when ever I make a change to the edmx and save all of the extra partial classes that I have in my .Model project are deleted.

This only happened with the last upgrade. I can't find a setting that controls this. Does anyone know how this behavior can be turned off?

Comment: We haven't seen this behavior and aren't able to reproduce it.  If you're still seeing the problem, which version of Visual Studio are you using, and which DevForce template?

Comment: I am using VS 2012  11.0.61030.00 Update 4. The template manifest says 7.2.3.0

Comment: This behavior is strange, as there have not been any changes made to the EDM extension recently.  Which version of DevForce were you using previously?  Is there anything else you can tell me - have you moved the generated classes to a subfolder?  Are errors displayed in the DevForce output pane?  Which OS are you running?  Have you customized the T4 templates?

Comment: I just did it again, on close look the files are deleted when I do an update model from database. But this also runs the T4 tempate. Not sure if it is the Update or the t4 doing it. I was on 7.2 before but I only just switched up to EF 6.1 being included in the project

Comment: Ok I did a test, it is the Update model from database that is deleting all my partial classes, not the T4 template. Any ideas why it is doing that?

Comment: No idea, as I still can't reproduce this behavior.  Take a look at the various "DevForce Code Generation" properties in the property window for the model to make sure everything looks OK.  Maybe also try one of the DevForce samples to see if the same problem exists there.